# Count the active threads at a time in C#

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading

I am using a fileSystemWatcher and  with Created event listener  i am starting a new Thread to process the file contents and do some time consuming operations. The code is like below

```
    fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(folderToWatchFor);
    fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;       
    fileSystemWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileCreated);

    private void FileCreated(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

        string file_path = e.FullPath;
        string file_name = e.Name;
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => processFileThread(file_name, file_path));
        thread.Start();
        //count the active threads here??
    }
```

I like to get the active number of Threads to see how many live threads are there at a time and for this i used

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count
```

But it returned a different counts for me. Like i simply copied 1 file , so only 1 thread is active but the above code returned 23.

So  how can i count the active threads started in the function FileCreated()

Comment: You make a static variable and have each thread increase the variable by one when it starts and decrease it by one when it ends.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Yes this will work. But curious to know the .Net framework supports any such features?

Comment: Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3069769/1356478

Comment: You will get a higher number since the .NET framework starts various background threads automatically. E.g. the threadpool, maybe ones for the garbage collector, etc.

Comment: Did you debug your code or let it run by itself? Visual studio and the debugger will start a few threads.

Comment: its a windows service.. So option to do debug is limited. As i am doing stress test with 1000's of files

Comment: You need to write logging code in your service and have a feature to turn on debug mode basically... This way you can track your service for development and turn it off for real deployment.  You get the idea... Services can be nasty without this done from the start IMO.

Answer (score 2):

The

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count
```

will return all threads for your application.
There is no direct possibility to get only your own thread. On top of the operating system threads are the threads of the .net framework itself (due to this the high number of threads).

If you use a static variable be sure to implement locking / interlocked due to multi-threaded access.

```
private int _threadCounter = 0;
private object _threadCounterLock = new object();

lock(_threadCounterLock)
  _threadCounter++;
```